# How to add page break in TuesPechkin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pechkin

Im using TuesPechkin to generate a pdf using html page. I need to add a page break(New page). How can I do it...?

Comment: The css properties `page-break-before: always;` or `page-break-after` should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

use this in your html string ..TESTED

```
<div style='page-break-after:always'></div>
```